# AS/400 Wont compile Printer File under RDP 8

Tags: ibm-midrange, rational-developer-for-i

I'm currently taking a college course on AS400 (IBM I) and i've been good until Chapter 11, dealing with RDP 8.0. Either way, i managed to get through the assignment up until the point where i'm required to copy a previously crafted physical file called "EMPPFLP" under the library "INTROCLASS".

I copied the file over to my personal library under "QDDSSRC" source and then right clicked on it (EMPPFLP) and selected Compile then CRTPRTF and i get this.

> Job 942098/DDELAP01/QDFTJOBD submitted to job queue QBATCH in library
>   QGPL.
>
> CRTPRTF SRCFILE(DDELAP01/QDDSSRC) SRCMBR(EMPPFLP) REPLACE(*YES)
>   OPTION(*EVENTF)  FILE(DDELAP01/EMPPFLP) Errors in DDS not allowed with
>   specified GENLVL. Cause . . . . . :   Either the severity level of the
>   errors found in DDS was greater than or equal to the error generation
>   level (GENLVL parameter), or GENLVL(0) was specified. Recovery  . . .
>   :   See the DDS source listing for the GENLVL value and error
>   messages.  Either correct the errors or change the GENLVL value on the
>   command, and then try the request again. File EMPPFLP not created in
>   library DDELAP01. Cause . . . . . :   The file was not created because
>   of errors. Recovery  . . . :   See the error messages previously
>   listed.  Correct the errors, and then try the request again.

[image]

I will appreciate any help guys, not sure whats going on here, I already posted questions for professor but i've received no response and i need to submit this assignment by 12am.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what college teaches AS400?

Comment: Baker College, not sure why i'm required to take the course.. Sigh, not a big fan of this OS.

Comment: How did you fix this? I'm also taking the same course. It's the most useless course I've taken.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 Wish I could help, completed trashed all that from my brain... Don't remember any of it! Sorry!! Check my accepted answer below tho. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> CPD5248: File specified on REF or REFFLD keyword not found.

The library containing the file `EMPPFL` used in your [REFFLD](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzakd/rzakdmstptreffl.htm) statement is not in your [library list](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp).

Either replace `*LIBL` with the actual library name that contains the file or add it to your library list with the `ADDLIBLE` command (or other method appropriate for your development environment).

> CPD7528: Number of decimal replace positions not valid

This is caused because the field definition can not be found because of the previous error.

---

The `REFFLD` keyword allows you to pull field attributes from a file (table) instead of hardcoding every one.

The error indicates that the file being referenced, EMPPFL, can not be found in your library list.  The library list is similar to the PATH in Windows/Linux/etc.

In order to resolve the error you must help the system find the EMPPFL file.  This can be done by explicitly pointing to the library containing the file or including the file in a library within your library list.

---

If you can provide the output from the following commands it will help resolve the issue:

```
DSPLIBL OUTPUT(*PRINT)

DSPOBJD *LIBL/EMPPFL *FILE OUTPUT(*PRINT)

DSPOBJD *ALLUSR/EMPPFL *FILE OUTPUT(*PRINT)
```

Note that the second command should return a message "Object EMPPFL in *LIBL type *FILE not found".

Comment: Thank you James, i tried to edit the file and did multiple versions of it, the way i thought was correct but still no luck. The file runs fine under the default library, when i copy it over to my library it gives me the errors i posted above.

Comment: @Intrus That's odd that you can create the file in it's original location but not when the source is copied to your library.  I would copy the DDS source for `EMPPFL` into your library and create that file first and then qualify the REFFLD with your library name `REFFLD(EMPPFR/EMPNO DDELAP01/EMPPFL)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, great answer and very detailed! I will try this as soon as i get home from work this afternoon and keep you posted. Thanks again James.

Answer (score 0):

I know pretty much nothing about the AS400, but did find an article that describes the error message shown in your image:

**Message**
Number of decimal replace positions not valid.

**Cause**
The number of decimal replace positions for the EDTWRD or EDTCDE keyword must equal the field length. The number of decimal replace positions is the sum of the number of blanks and the first stop-zero-suppression character. If the first character in the EDTWRD is a stop-zero-suppression character, one additional blank may be specified.

**Recovery**
Change either the field length or the value on the EDTWRD or EDTCDE keyword to make the field length the same as the number of decimal replace positions. Then try the request again.

http://www.iseriesworld.net/?messages=cl&prefix=cpd&code=7528

I hope that helps.  Good luck with your class and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thank you Eric, i'm still fighting with it. Can't seem to be able to fix the issue, i tried the suggestion from that website but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

It seem a GENLVL error. You should have a look on the SPLF which product after you compile. There should be some useful message on there

Comment: Hey Allen, thank you for the response. Is there a way to check this via the RDP 8? Or is it better to use a terminal session. What exactly is the "SPLF" is it a Logical file??? Thanks!

Comment: SPLF is spool file. I don't have many experience on RDP8, but what I know is when you crash on compilng the PF, the System will generate a spool file. It record the detail of error. I have not worked on as400 for a long time. Sorry for I can't remember how to view this file.